# What combos are available and what are their effects?

Tags: plague-inc, plague-inc-evolved

I have noticed on multiple playthroughs that evolving certain symptoms can result in a combination symptom, as follows:

[image]

In this instance, sneezing and diarrhoea are causing "unwanted accidents", which draws additional attention to your plague.

What other symptoms can be combined to create a combo and what the effects of each combo are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Plague Inc. Wiki](http://the-plague-inc.wikia.com/wiki/Combos):

## Standard combos

#### Oops symptom combo

Diarrhoea + Sneezing

> Sneezing and diarrhoea are causing unwanted accidents, lowering productivity and drawing attention to [disease name]

- Slightly increases Infectivity
- Slightly increases Severity
- Slightly slows down Cure Research

#### Profuse bleeding symptom combo

Haemophilia + Skin Lesions

> Haemophilia and skin lesions are causing the infected to have blood pouring out of their skin, making [disease name] far more dangerous

- Slightly increases Lethality
- Large increase in Infectivity
- Even larger increase in Infectivity when paired with Blood 1 and 2 transmissions

#### Projectile Vomiting

Coughing + Vomiting

> Coughing and vomiting are causing the infected to projectile vomit, increasing the infectivity of [disease name]

- Slightly increases Infectivity

#### Swine Flu symptom combo

Coughing + Diarrhoea + Insomnia + Pneunomia + Vomiting + Livestock 2

> [Disease name] has similar symptoms to Swine Flu. Doctors researching the cure are wasting time looking into cures for Swine Flu. Cure will take longer

- Slightly slows down Cure Research

#### Public Defecation symptom combo

Diarrhoea + Insanity

> Diarrhoea and insanity are causing the people to defecate in public (and everywhere else!) Everyone is increasingly focused on developing a cure

- Slightly increases Infectivity
- Slightly speeds up Cure Research

#### Waking Dead symptom combo

Anaemia + Insomnia

> Insomnia and anaemia are causing people to walk around grey with tiredness. Scientists working on the cure for [disease name] are less productive

- Slightly slows down Cure Research

---

## Necroa Virus Combos

#### Vampire Bat

Vampiric Hunger + Bat 2

- Slightly increases Severity
- Slightly increases Infectivity
- Slightly increases Lethality

#### Tank

Anabolic Boost + Bone Dysplasia

- Slightly increases Severity

#### Spitter

Naja Mortis + Enhanced Sensory Integration

- Slightly increases Severity

#### Boomer

Autothysis + Liquefactive Necrosis

- Slightly increases Severity

#### Cranial Dispersion

Cranial Elephantitis + Air 3

- Increases Severity

#### Walking Contradiction

Photophobia + Cathameral Shift

- Slightly decreases Severity

#### Runner

Enhanced Motor Control + Engorged Quadriceps

- Slightly increases Severity

#### Bath Time

Autophagia + Polyphagia + Cannibalism

- Increases Infectivity

---

The Neurax Worm does not feature any Combos.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion @Compro01. Sorry it got automatically rejected, because I submitted another edit myself.